# Creating cache system in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, api, caching

I've made a native javascript class using http requests to get api data from a site. But the website that I request data, has a request limit. So I thought about caching the data but I couldn't find any clear sources about it.

Is there a way to cache the data in native javascript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `LocalStorage` or `IndexedDB` or `WebSQL` (in HTML5)

pre HTML5 you can use a Flash or Java Applet.